# Transforming JSON data into individual rows in SQL table using json_table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some old data, that looks something like this:

| id | json | otherData |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"A": [12538, 12546], "B": [12537, 12544, 12547, 12553], "C": [12598, 12541, 12548, 12550, 12551, 12565], "D": [12599, 12542, 12543, 12545, 12552], "F": [], "G": []} | otherData |

For migration, I need each value joind with id and other data, aswell as the key. something like this:

| id | key | value | otherData |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 12538 | otherData |
| 1 | A | 12546 | otherData |
| 2 | B | 12537 | otherData |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I tried with json_table, but wasn't able to get this working. I get all rows of this json table, but all are null.

```sql
select `A`
from my_table,
     json_table(json_col,
                '$.*' columns (
                    `A` INT path '$."A"'

                    )
         ) x;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Incorrect parsing path, must be `'$.A[*]' COLUMNS (A INT PATH '$')`. https://dbfiddle.uk/OqXeyXYd

Comment: Path must be like `'$[*]' columns`

Comment: Try: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Dl_VPWNP).